# Are feature requests allowed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wonder whether feature requests for the Mathematica system are allowed on the main site or on the meta site?

Comment: Things you want added to *Mathematica*?  Stack exchange is limited to question/answer type posts.  You might have better luck posting on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/) which has no such limitation on the type of post.

Comment: Alternately to what @JasonB. if it's something you think would be cool and would like help implementing yourself those are *definitely* on top. Not all Mathematica features must/should/can come from WRI. Developing the independence to implement stuff yourself is important.

Comment: If you think about it a bit, in a lot of cases you will probably find a way to formulate a legitimate question in such away, that a feature request is obviously implied (there is also the tag code request imo). Considering the amount of (helpful) traffic here, this will greatly increase the likelihood that a) you are empowered to add the feature yourself, b) somebody else picks it up (look no further than @b3m2a1 ;-) or c) WRI takes note - after all we are the market.

Answer (score 11):

No, feature requests are off-topic here or on the main site. They wouldn't make much sense either, because this site is community driven and no official channel to communicate with Wolfram Research. As already said in the comments, the official Wolfram Community or the Wolfram Support is the correct way for such requests.